# Could not find generator 'serializer'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, active-model-serializers

I am trying to generate serializer `question`
After running this command `rails g serializer question`

I see the following error message:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 3128
Could not find generator 'serializer'.
Run `bin/rails generate --help` for more options.
```

I've already tried stopping `spring`

ruby `3.0.2`, rails `6.1.4`

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to install `active_model_serializers` gem before :)

Comment: the first time only installing `active_model_serializers` worked for me, I had to run 
`spring stop` after other times